# go-lang simple webserver : serve static image

Tags: go

I want to write a simple webserver in go that does the following: when i go to http://example.go:8080/image, it returns a static image.
I'm following an example i found [here](http://golang.org/doc/articles/wiki/). In this example they implement this method:

```
func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "Hi there, I love %s!", r.URL.Path[1:])
}
```

and then refer to it here :

```
...
...
http.HandleFunc("/", handler)
```

Now, what i wanna do is serve an image instead of writing to the string.
How would i go about that?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can serve static files using the [`http.FileServer`](http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#FileServer) function.

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    http.Handle("/", http.StripPrefix("/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("path/to/file"))))
    if err := http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil); err != nil {
        log.Fatal("ListenAndServe: ", err)
    }
}
```

EDIT: More [idiomatic](http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#introduction) code.

EDIT 2: This code above will return an image `image.png` when the browser requests http://example.go/image.png

The [`http.StripPrefix`](http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#StripPrefix) function here is strictly unnecessary in this case as the path being handled is the web root. If the images were to be served from the path http://example.go/images/image.png then the line above would need to be `http.Handle("/images/", http.StripPrefix("/images/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("path/to/file"))))`.

[Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/e9kx6mJpI1)

Comment: thanks a lot! can you add a couple of word about what the StripPrefix and FileServer mean and used in this context?

Comment: StripPrefix isn't really necessary in this case as you're serving from the root of the web-server. It's really required when you want to server from a different path. Have a look at http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#StripPrefix and http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#FileServer .